# VBA - Ignore a sheet when consolidating other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where I need to consolidate some sheets and not others.

The consolidate part was easy (thanks to http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=151).

I am struggling to ignore a sheet called "Mapping".

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()
Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
Dim trg As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
Dim rng As Range 'Range object
Dim colCount As Integer 'Column count in tables in the worksheets

Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = "Master" Then
        MsgBox "There is a worksheet called as 'Master'." & vbCrLf & _
          "Please remove or rename this worksheet since 'Master' would be" & _
          "the name of the result worksheet of this process.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next sht

 'We don't want screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet
Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
 'Rename the new worksheet
trg.Name = "Master"
 'Get column headers from the first worksheet
 'Column count first
Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)
colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
 'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed
With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
    .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
     'Set font as bold
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

 'We can start loop
For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
     'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
    If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
        Exit For
    End If
     'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
     'Put data into the Master worksheet
    trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
Next sht
 'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
trg.Columns.AutoFit

 'Screen updating should be activated
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just add `If sht.Name = "Mapping" Then` where you need it.

Comment: Or maybe you need `If sht.Name <> "Mapping"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the last loop to look like this:

```
' We can start loop
For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets

    ' If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
    If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
        Exit For
    End If

    If Not sht.Name = "Mapping" Then
        ' Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
        Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
        ' Put data into the Master worksheet
        trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value

    End If

Next sht
```

**Explanation:**

As this script loops through each sheet combining data, your code first checks if the sheet is the last in the workbook.  If so, it stops looping and does nothing with that last sheet.  I added code just below that point.  The line `If Not sht.Name = "Mapping" Then` tells VBA to only execute the code inside the `IF` block if the current sheet in the loop is not named "Mapping".

Comment: thank you for your help! I had to do one change, but it was on the file itself: the sheet "Mapping" was the first sheet, and had a different format from the others. Therefore I had to move the sheet to the end of the book, as otherwise, it would affect the format of my "Master" sheet and give me the wrong information.

Comment: That’s great!  Glad I could help.

Comment: Friendly hint: 65,536 was the maximum number of spreadsheet rows supported by Excel 97 up to Excel 2003, so replace the number by `sht.Rows.Count` if you are using more up to date versions as well.